# How to select content between symbol with line break

Tags: regex

I have been playing around for hours and cannot come out with a solution.

Assume we have the below text:

```
The `replace()` method is used to replace a substring or regular expression in a string with a new substring or function. The basic syntax for this method is as follows:

***
string.replace(searchValue, replaceValue)
***

Here, `string` is the original string where the replacement will take place, `searchValue` is the substring or regular expression that needs to be replaced, and `replaceValue` is the new substring that will replace the old one.

For example, if we have a string `var str = "Hello World"`, and we want to replace the word "World" with "JavaScript", we can use the `replace()` method as follows:

***javascript
var str = "Hello World";
var newStr = str.replace("World", "JavaScript");

console.log(newStr); // Output: "Hello JavaScript"
***
```

What I want to select is the:

```
***
string.replace(searchValue, replaceValue)
***
```

And the:

```
***javascript
var str = "Hello World";
var newStr = str.replace("World", "JavaScript");

console.log(newStr); // Output: "Hello JavaScript"
***
```

My current Regex is `***(.+?)?\n((?:.+\n)+?)***`

Let me explain a bit, `***(.+?)?` because the word javascript after the *** is optional as it might not exist or it might be other word, then ((?:.+\n)+?) means one sentence at a line with one or more. ( sorry, I need the capturing group )

It works if there is no line breaks like:

```
***javascript
var str = "Hello World";
var newStr = str.replace("World", "JavaScript");
console.log(newStr); // Output: "Hello JavaScript"
***
```

But the line break is optional, because I don't know there would be line break or not, so the Regex need to work whether there is no line break, or there is one line break or more line break...

The * is actually ` because hard to escape it in the editor here. You can try [here](https://regexr.com/7dli9)

Comment: Why don't you use a Markdown files parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `s` flag on the regexp to allow `.` to match newlines.

You also need to escape the `*` characters in the regexp.

````js
const text = `The \`replace()\` method is used to replace a substring or regular expression in a string with a new substring or function. The basic syntax for this method is as follows:

\`\`\`
string.replace(searchValue, replaceValue)
\`\`\`

Here, \`string\` is the original string where the replacement will take place, \`searchValue\` is the substring or regular expression that needs to be replaced, and \`replaceValue\` is the new substring that will replace the old one.

For example, if we have a string \`var str = "Hello World"\`, and we want to replace the word "World" with "JavaScript", we can use the \`replace()\` method as follows:

\`\`\`javascript
var str = "Hello World";
var newStr = str.replace("World", "JavaScript");

console.log(newStr); // Output: "Hello JavaScript"
\`\`\``;

matches = text.match(/```(.*?)\n(.+?)```/sg);

console.log(matches);
````

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mentioned that I replace the \ with * because hard to escape here in StackOverflow. It doesn't work to use the dotall flag as you can try here: https://regexr.com/7dli9

Comment: It works in my code snippet.

Comment: To put literal backticks in the code block, escape them with backslash.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to make it clearer. If I choose the single line (dotall) flag, it just going to select everything from the first ``` and the last ``` of the entire context...

Comment: It won't because of the non-greedy `.*?`

Comment: Please just go the link and press the single line (dotall) then you will understand what I mean

Comment: https://regexr.com/7dlj4

Comment: Bro, I need the capturing group...If that could be such simple, it is the best...Haha

Comment: Then put a capturing group around `.+?`

Comment: Can you show me in the link again, bro. Hard to understand like this, sorry I'm stupid

Comment: Click on Run Code Snippet above to see that it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "Then put a capturing group around .+?"...

Comment: I've updated the answer. I have two capture groups, one for the language name after the first triple-backtick, and another for the rest of the code.

Comment: I have been playing it like really hours, don't know why you're so genius